# Question regarding implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations

I have a question that I think is closely related to the implicit function theorem but I am unsure of how to solve it. Does the following proposition hold?

> Let $ a < b$ and $y:(a,b) \to \mathbb R$ be a function. Furthermore, let $F\colon (a,b) \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function such that $$\forall x \in (a,b): F(x,y(x)) = 0 \\ \forall (x,y) \in (a,b) \times \mathbb R: \frac{\partial}{\partial y}F(x,y) >0.$$
>   Then $y$ is continuously differentiable.

I think this must be true, but I can't transfer from the local case to the global case and also I don't know if the function that the implicit function theorem gives me can be glued together so that it equals $y$ everywhere. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a point $x_0\in(a,b)$, and let $y(x_0)=:y_0$. Then $F(x_0,y_0)=0$, and $${\partial F\over\partial y}(x_0,y_0)>0\ .$$
The implicit function theorem then guarantees the following: There is a window $$W:=[x_0-h,x_0+h]\times[y_0-c,y_0+c]\ \subset \ (a,b)\times{\mathbb R}$$ with center $(x_0,y_0)$ and a $C^1$-function
$$\psi:\quad [x_0-h,x_0+h]\to [y_0-c,y_0+c],\qquad x\mapsto y=\psi(x)$$
with $\psi(x_0)=y_0$, such that
$$\bigl\{(x,y)\bigm| F(x,y)=0\bigr\}\cap W=\bigl\{(x,\psi(x))\bigm|x_0-h\leq x\leq x_0+h\bigr\}\ .$$
This means that within $W$ the set $F(x,y)=0$ coincides with the graph of $\psi$. This implies that $$y(x)=\psi(x)\qquad(x_0-h\leq x\leq x_0+h)\ ,$$ hence $x\mapsto y(x)$ is $C^1$ in the neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Why is it guaranteed that the values of $x\mapsto y(x)$ are within $[y_0 - c,y_0 + c]$?

Comment: The $h$ and $c$ are not uniquely determined. But the theorem says that such a window exists. People often just speak of "a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$".

Comment: Yes, but you claim that in this neighbourhood y(x) = g(x). What if y is so large that its values are outside this neighbourhood?

Comment: If $F(x,y)=x-\sin y$ and $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$ you could have $x\mapsto y(x)$ with densely distributed jumps of $2\pi$. The implicit function theorem guarantees that there is only one $x\mapsto y(x)$ which is continuous at $x=0$ and has the value $0$ there.

Comment: Yes. I just don't understand your step where from the fact that the level set of $F$ intersected with W equals the graph of $\psi$ around $x_0$ you deduce that $y(x) = \psi(x)$, because a priori we don't know that $y$ is continuous and might as well have values outside of W. Do you understand my problem?

Comment: I think I got it now. You basically use that $F(x,z) = 0$ if and only if $z = y(x)$ since $\partial_z F(x,z) > 0$ and $F(x,y(x)) = 0$ for each $x$.